# How to prove tautology from entail?

Tags: propositional-calculus

If $\emptyset$ $\models$ $\phi$, can we say $\phi$ is a tautology because we can entail $\phi$ from nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. To say :

> $\Gamma \vDash \phi$

means that :

> for every *valuation* $v$, if $v$ satisfy every formula in $\Gamma$, then $v$ satisfy also $\phi$.

Thus, when we have : $\emptyset \vDash \phi$, this means that :

> for every valuation $v$, if $v$ satisfy all the formulae in $\emptyset$, then $v$ satisfy also $\phi$.

But there are **no** formulae in $\emptyset$ and thus the conditional in the definition of $\vDash$ is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Conclusion : every valuation $v$ satisfy $\phi$, and this amounts to say that $\phi$ is a *tautology*.